# Designing a library API to allow for interactivity

Tags: c++, python, qt

The application I'm currently working on is deeply coupled to the UI framework in use (Qt at the moment). I would like to separate the UI-specific code from the rest as much as possible, with the goal of creating a library for use with other toolkits in the near future.

I have already started this work but I am struggling with the architecture of the application when it comes to interactivity: moving code out of the UI is not that hard, but I would like to keep things such as progress indicators and warning message boxes working. One thing I am doing right now is to pass a "show_progress" functor that takes one argument and updates the progress dialog, but I am not sure if this will work in the long run; I would pretty much either need multiple functors per library call or create one big interface that would have methods for progress bars, message boxes, etc.

Is there a more scalable approach to help me sort these problems out?

Comment: Questions asking for ["some examples" will get closed and deleted](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed) on this site, as well as asking for 3rd party resources, that is why I tried to fix that. You may be looking for [Model-View-Presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct approach I know for decoupling general logic for controlling the UI (like progress indicators) from a specific UI technology (like Qt) is the [Model-View-Presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) pattern. This works as follows:

- For each Window / Dialog / Form / View, one has to define an abstract interface class, and the Window / Dialog / Form / View class (from the specific UI framework) will have to implement it.
- The controlling of the UI action is done by a corresponding "Presenter" class (usually one Presenter per View), which gets an object of the View's interface injected at construction time. The Presenter will usually not contain any UI framework specific code, it can be placed in a lib which does not even reference the UI framework.

Maybe that is what you meant with *"create one big interface that would have methods for progress bars, message boxes"*. Depending on the number of features of each view, the required interfaces may have a certain size - still it will be only a fraction of the view's code itself, hence this approach is definitely scalable.

It's drawback is you need now three classes where you formerly had one, and you have to make further design decisions how much logic you put into the view and how much into the presenter. But besides the option of using a different UI framework, it has another benefit: presenter classes are way more unit-testable than view classes, where the code can usually only be driven by the UI framework, and not easily by the unit testing framework. For testing presenter classes, one can inject a mock view for testing purposes.